# Use HTTP Auth only if accessing a specific domain

Tags: apache, authentication, .htaccess

I've got several sites:  `example.com`, `example1.com`, and `example2.com`.  All of them point to my server's `/public_html` folder, which is my Apache root folder.

What do I need to add to my `.htaccess` file to use http authentication only if the user is coming from `example2.com`?  `example.com` and `example1.com` should NOT use authentication.

I know I need something like

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
AuthUserFile "/path/to/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

But I only want to require a password if the user is visiting `example2.com`.

**Edit**

Using an approach suggested in an answer, I have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^(.*)$ testauth
<IfDefine testauth>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index2.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfDefine>
```

I know that the mod_setenvif.c module is enabled (I verified with an <IfModule> block), but it would appear that "testauth" is never getting defined, because my test to verify (redirecting to index2.php) is not executing (whereas it was getting executed in my <IfModule> block).  Any ideas why?

Comment: If all domains are pointing to the same place, why would you want to protect only one of them? 
If you actually serve different content, why not have a saner approach like one folder per domain?

Comment: I'm running a multisite Drupal installation out of my /public_html folder, and I want to create a blanket http auth over one of the sites, in addition to that site's normal user login.

Comment: Drupal's multisite allows me to run different websites off the same set of PHP files, but with different databases (so different content). I could do a second installation in a subfolder, but that would require me to maintain to distinct sets of files and modules.

Comment: According to the documentation http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ifdefine , IfDefine is processed at startup.

Comment: ifDefine doesn't work with internal environment variables set by setenv or setenvif, only -D flags at server startup

Answer (score 26):

How about something along the lines of this in the htaccess file in the document root:

```
# set the "require_auth" var if Host ends with "example2.com"
SetEnvIfNoCase Host example2\.com$ require_auth=true

# Auth stuff
AuthUserFile /var/www/htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic

# Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from everyone
Deny from all
# except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any
# 1. a valid authenticated user
Require valid-user
# or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

This will make it so authentication is not required unless the host ends with `example2.com` (e.g. `www.example2.com`, `dev.example2.com`, etc). The expression can be tweaked if needed. Any other host will cause the `require_auth` var not to get set so authentication is *not* required. If this needs to be the other way around, the last line could be changed to: `Allow from env=require_auth`, removing the **!**.

Comment: For me !require_auth doesn't work, but this does:
Allow from all
Deny from env=require_auth
Require valid-user
Satisfy any

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: afaik users might be able to exploit this by requesting "example2.com." (notice the dot at the end). So your rule should rather be `SetEnvIfNoCase Host example2\.com\.?$ ...` otherwise the content might be still visible without protection.

Comment: I rolled back the change, the approach @MaximKrizhanovsky suggested does not work under my testing scenario but the original answer did.

Answer (score 22):

Apache 2.4 offers a semantic alternative with the [If](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if) directive:

```
<If "req('Host') == 'example2.com'">
    AuthUserFile /path/to/htpasswd
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Password Protected"
    Require valid-user
</If>
<Else>
    Require all granted
</Else>
```

Comment: Works. Awsome!!

Comment: I get interval server error, suggestions? Apache running 2.4.37

Comment: @maestroosram Be wary of syntax errors. What does your Apache error log say?

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: beautiful, thank you

Answer (score 5):

Here is one recommendation:

Create a file called `common.conf` and save in an accessible location

In this file place the Apache configuration common to all sites (hosts).

The remove the current single VirtualHost entry an replace with VirtualHost entries as follows:

```
# These are the password protected hosts
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias example1.com

Include /path-to-common-configuration/common.conf

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
AuthUserFile "/path/to/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
</VirtualHost>

# These are hosts not requiring authentication
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example2.com
ServerAlias example3.com

Include /path-to-common-configuration/common.conf

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if DanH would be helped by an approach that allows access per IP address?

Something like

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr 1\.2\.3\.4 AllowMeIn
SetEnvIfNoCase Host this\.host\.is\.ok\.com AllowMeIn
SetEnvIfNoCase Host this\.host\.is\.also\.ok\.com AllowMeIn
```

and then in your Drupal "container"

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from env=AllowMeIn
```

should do the trick.

Any host that is "live" should be configured to "AllowMeIn", or else you have to come from a known IP address (ie you and other developers).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be putting per-vhost configuration into .htaccess. Instead, put the config block in the VirtualHost block in the proper config file in `/etc/apache/sites-enabled/*`.

Comment: I don't have access to the vhost files, unfortunately.  I'm running all this on a shared hosting server through CPanel. =(