# host-specific .htaccess using if

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On a service available through different subdomains/domains, I want to be able to use only one .htaccess file. For each possible value of `%{HTTP_HOST}`, I have set up `if` blocks like this:

```
<if "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'staging.project.example.org'">
    [detailed configuration...]
</if>

<if "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'development.project.example.org'">
    [detailed configuration...]
</if>
```

This works well with access configuration lines like:

```
<if "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'staging.project.example.org'">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile ".htusers"
    Require user example
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
   Allow from xxx.xx.xx.xxx
</if>
```

But `RewriteRule` lines like this will be ignored by Apache:

```
<if "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'production.project.example.org'">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.project.example/maintenance.html [R=307,P]
</if>
```

Is it possible to use `RewriteRule` with `if` in .htaccess? I think it might be because of

> "Only directives that support the directory context can be used within
>   this configuration section."
>   in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#if

but is there a way around this?

Comment: Mod_rewrite does support the directory context, so it passes that criteria, although I'm not saying it should definitely work. When you say it doesn't work, in what way? What happens when you try it?

Comment: Nothing happens - the RewriteRules inside ``if``are ignored.

Comment: you should just concatenate "If" statements or declare and if that checks for both things, also, do not mix P and R flags in mod_rewrite since they are meant for different things, do you want to redirect or  rev proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: For host-specific rules within the same .htaccess file, I did this, which uses a logic similar to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11646997/4453939).

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host staging.project.example.org $ require_auth=true
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/path/to/your/.htusers"
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from env=require_auth
Allow from xxx.xx.xx.xx # to allow certain IPs without login
Require user ... # users from the .htusers file above that are allowed to login
Satisfy any
```

Using this setting, any access using the host `staging.project.example.org` will need to go through authentication or match a whitelisted IP.

Multiple lines of `SetEnvIfNoCase` are possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think rewrite rules can work in an `if` directive, but you can include the same logic in the rewrite rule itself:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} production.project.example.org
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.project.example/maintenance.html [R=307,P]
```

The `RewriteCond` statements form a logical `AND` giving you the same logic as if you encapsulated in `if` directives

Comment: instead of flagging my comment for removal, at least try to fix the R,P flags in your answer, stackoverflow doesn't let me because its just 2 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If and mod_rewrite in some cases can play the exact same roles, for instance, in mod_rewrite an "If" would be like RewriteCond.

So.. do not mix them together, use one, or the other.